# An efficient way to resegment tokenized text into phrases

Tags: nlp, preprocessing, tokenization

I have text **tokenized on the word level** and few lists of phrases stored as tuples.

What would be the most efficient way to resegment (and store) the text into **phrases?**

For example, a sentence like:

"He didn't work hard."

Which is now tokenized as:

"He" "did" "n't" "work" "hard" "."

Would become:

"He" "did" "n't" "work hard" "."

Assuming that "work hard" would be one of the phrases I have.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Can you please give an example?

Comment: Sure, the text file is tokenized into words, and I have a list of tuples with each of which contains phrases. What I would like to get is the same text but tokenized into phrases whenever that would be possible, so with a sentence:

"The young couple was looking into the moon."

Let's say that "the young couple" and "into the moon" are in my phrase-set, the resegmented text would be something like this (instead of: token token token; where token is mostly words):  "the young couple" "was" "looking" "into the moon" (4 tokens instead of 8 in this case).

Comment: Actually, seems like MWETokenizer may be what I'm looking for...

Comment: I think that the most direct way would be to (1) tokenize the phrases, (2) search for the tokenized phrases in the tokenized text.

Comment: Thank you Erwan, I already have them tokenized. I guess what I was asking was how would you go through with marking these phrases (combining into 1 token).

Comment: As far as I know the only way is to loop over the tokens in the sentences, and whenever a token can be the first token of a phrase check whether the following tokens correspond to the phrase or not.

Comment: Thank you for your help!